# Get list with all values from all cells of pd DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pd Dataframe `cooc_all` (symmetric matrix) from which I would like to create a list that contains all the values from the DataFrame.

Currently, I have done this as follows:

```
pd_list = []

for i in range(0,40):
    for j in range(i, 40):
        pd_list.append(cooc_all[j][i])
```

Is this the best way to do it? Or are there faster/shorter ways?

Comment: `cooc_all.values.tolist()`?

Comment: Note that `cooc_all` is a symmetric matrix and only the top half of values should be captured. Your appraoch captures all, and thus the list contains many `nan` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.tril` to extract the lower triangle of the symmetric matrix, then flatten it with `F`ortran order (column-major) to match your list and finally take out the zeros coming from upper side:

```
>>> out = np.tril(df).ravel(order="F")
>>> out[out != 0].tolist()
```

Comment: Thank you @Mustafa. Is there also a method to extract the top traingle of the symmetric matrix?

Comment: @Emil Yes, `np.triu` `:)` (*u* for upper, *l* for lower)

Answer (score 3):

Try with `ravel` then `tolist`

```
outlist = df.values.ravel().tolist()
```

Update only get the upper tri

```
idx = np.tril_indices(len(df))
df[idx] = np.nan
df.stack().tolist()
```

Comment: please note the `i` in `for j in range(i, 40)` in the question

Comment: Note that `cooc_all` is a symmetric matrix and only the top half of values should be captured. Your appraoch captures all, and thus the output contains many `nan` values.